# HTML Input Tage Values not saving in SQLite Database - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to save data from HTML Form to SQLite database. My database is connected to my app and project. I am able to enter from Django Admin, **but my values from Input tag are not going in database.**

Views.py

```
def add_record(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    
    ref_no = request.POST.get('ref_no')
    token_no = request.POST.get('token_no')
    agent_name = request.POST.get('agent_name')
    trip_no = request.POST.get('trip_no')
    date = request.POST.get('date')
    vehicle_no = request.POST.get('vehicle_no')
    bora = request.POST.get('bora')
    katta = request.POST.get('katta')
    plastic = request.POST.get('plastic')
    farmer_name = request.POST.get('farmer_name')
    farmer_address = request.POST.get('farmer_address')
    farmer_mob = request.POST.get('farmer_mob')
    gross_weight = request.POST.get('gross_weight')
    tier_weight = request.POST.get('tier_weight')
    net_weight = request.POST.get('net_weight')
    bora_weight = request.POST.get('bora_weight')
    suddh_weight = request.POST.get('suddh_weight')
    loading = request.POST.get('loading')
    unloading = request.POST.get('unloading')
    unloading_point = request.POST.get('unloading_point')
    dharamkanta_man = request.POST.get('daramkanta_man')
    rate = request.POST.get('rate')
    bardana = request.POST.get('rate')
    gross_total = request.POST.get('gross_total')
    deduction = request.POST.get('deduction')
    kanta = request.POST.get('kanta')
    hemali = request.POST.get('hemali')
    our_vehicle_rent = request.POST.get('our_vehicle_rent')
    agent_commission = request.POST.get('agent_commission')
    other_amt = request.POST.get('other_amt')
    other_remarks = request.POST.get('other_remarks')
    advance = request.POST.get('advance')
    net_total = request.POST.get('net_total')

    var_datasave = paddy_purchase(ref_no=ref_no,
                                  token_no=token_no,
                                  agent_name=agent_name,
                                  trip_no=trip_no,
                                  date=date,
                                  vehicle_no=vehicle_no,
                                  bora=bora,
                                  katta=katta,
                                  plastic=plastic,
                                  farmer_name=farmer_name,
                                  farmer_address=farmer_address,
                                  farm_mob=farmer_mob,
                                  gross_weight=gross_weight,
                                  tier_weight=tier_weight,
                                  net_weight=net_weight,
                                  bora_weight=bora_weight,
                                  suddh_weight=suddh_weight,
                                  loading=loading,
                                  unloading=unloading,
                                  unloading_point=unloading_point,
                                  dharamkanta_man=dharamkanta_man,
                                  rate=rate,
                                  bardana=bardana,
                                  gross_total=gross_total,
                                  deduction=deduction,
                                  kanta=kanta,
                                  hemali=hemali,
                                  our_vehicle_rent=our_vehicle_rent,
                                  agent_commission=agent_commission,
                                  other_amt=other_amt,
                                  other_remarks=other_remarks,
                                  advance=advance,
                                  net_total=net_total
                                  )

    var_datasave.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Record saved successfully.')
    return redirect('index')

return render(request, 'add.html')
```

Models.py

```
class paddy_purchase(models.Model):
    ref_no = models.IntegerField(primary_key='true')
    token_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique='true')
    agent_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    trip_no = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    vehicle_no = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bora = models.IntegerField()
    katta = models.IntegerField()
    plastic = models.IntegerField()
    farmer_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    farmer_address = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    farm_mob = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    gross_weight = models.IntegerField()
    tier_weight = models.IntegerField()
    net_weight = models.IntegerField()
    bora_weight = models.IntegerField()
    suddh_weight = models.FloatField()
    loading = models.IntegerField()
    unloading = models.IntegerField()
    unloading_point = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dharamkanta_man = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    bardana = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    gross_total = models.IntegerField()
    deduction = models.IntegerField()
    kanta = models.IntegerField()
    hemali = models.IntegerField()
    our_vehicle_rent = models.IntegerField()
    agent_commission = models.IntegerField()
    other_amt = models.IntegerField()
    other_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    advance = models.IntegerField()
    net_total = models.IntegerField()

# For returning data in ADMIN SITE
    def __str__(self):
        return 'paddy_purchase'
```

This is the error that I am having.
**NOT NULL constraint failed: main_paddy_purchase.token_no**

Here is a screen shot.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKkb2.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `token_no` is missing in `request.POST`.
You are using everywhere `request.POST.get(key)` which when isn't able find the key - returns `None`.
Probably you forgot to add corresponding `input` field with a proper name.

I suggest you take a look into Django Forms. And use them to validate the input of user and save changes into the database. The code will also look much smoother.

You can keep your **models.py**. Just rename the model to `PaddyPurchase` [according to the naming conventions in python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names).

[Then you would need to create ModelForm from your model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/), which will automatically take all the fields:

**forms.py**

```py
class PaddyPurchaseForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = PaddyPurchase
         fields = (
            "ref_no",
            "token_no",
            "agent_name",
            "trip_no",
            "date",
            "vehicle_no",
            "bora",
            "katta",
            "plastic",
            "farmer_name",
            "farmer_address",
            "farm_mob",
            "gross_weight",
            "tier_weight",
            "net_weight",
            "bora_weight",
            "suddh_weight",
            "loading",
            "unloading",
            "unloading_point",
            "dharamkanta_man",
            "rate",
            "bardana",
            "gross_total",
            "deduction",
            "kanta",
            "hemali",
            "our_vehicle_rent",
            "agent_commission",
            "other_amt",
            "other_remarks",
            "advance",
            "net_total",
        )
```

Then you could use the form in your **views.py**:

```py
from .forms import PaddyPurchaseForm
...
def add_record(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = PaddyPurchaseForm(request.POST))

      if form.is_valid():
         messages.success(request, 'Record saved successfully.')
         return redirect('index')
   else:
      form = PaddyPurchaseForm()

   return render(request, 'add.html', {'form':form})
```

Django Forms can be also used to render the form with all the neccessary inputs to the view, I suggest you try it. In order to do it, simply add `{{form}}` into your `<form ...> </form>`. *(Works only when you provided `form` in render function)*

You can read more about [django forms in official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/)

Comment: I tried it, but still data is not saving in the database.